# IS there a way to do zk proof on string?

Tags: encryption, hash

For example:
"I am a very secret person".

I'd like to show someone that this string includes 'secret' without revealing the rest of the string. Is there anyway?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for questions on programming. This question belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok. Thanks I closed it. :-) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99107/is-there-a-way-to-do-zk-proof-on-string